# GWT - DialogBox glass and GoogleChrome - glass doesn't repaint

Tags: java, gwt, google-chrome

I have just installed the newest google chrome and just trying to test GWT 2.3 code with DialogBox; For some reason the option like `setGlassEnabled(true);` works in a strange way :(

If chrome's scroll pane **(y position is 0)** the glass is painted correct

but if 
chrome's scroll pane **(y position is > 0)** then the glass is keeping in 0 position so the chrome's rest bottom  is not covered with glass :(

I am to show my constructor first glass options as

```
...
public MyDIalog() {

        this.setGlassEnabled(true);
        this.setAnimationEnabled(true);
        this.setModal(true);
        this.setPreviewingAllNativeEvents(true);
...
```

I am not pretty sure what makes the bug or something because the code works fine in IE and FF :S

So I guess in the chrome the glass position is always static or something and its location is always

> x,y{0,0} w,h{firstInitedWidth,firstInitedHeight}

So my question is is there a walk around for chrome?

Thanks

Comment: This is still the case using GWT 2.5.0 and Chrome 24.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Solved:

Make your own class that extends PopupPanel and add this:

```
    @Override
    public void setGlassEnabled(boolean enabled) {
        super.setGlassEnabled(enabled);
        Element glass = getGlassElement();
        if (glass != null) {
            glass.getStyle().setPosition(Position.FIXED);
        }
    }
```

This simply sets the position of the glass panel to fixed instead of absolute. This makes the panel not move with the scroll.

Comment: It is quite interesting... I didn't try this yet but is there a way not to override the method every time?

Comment: @user592704 Yes, just make your own class instead of an anonymous class. But to be exact, it actually seems like a bug from Chrome, because it works fine in Firefox. GWT seems to set the height of the glass pane to height of the root panel, but Chrome doesn't calculate it correctly if it is not displayed completly (has a scrollbar).

Answer (score 0):

Odd.... but I suppose worst case you can give the glass style some insane height/width in the css.

```
.gwt-PopupPanelGlass{
    height:15000 px;
    width:15000 px;
}
```

Comment: Beats me.... I've never seen this before.  I just figure if the default glass is staying at the top of the page, have it be really big so it covers everything it needs to.

Comment: Yes, it is staying at the top; :) 15000px is an interesting thought though why does the static effect happens? Maybe chrome need something else with GWT? I though GWT must work perfectly with chrome is it?

Comment: I am just wondering is there a way to make it repaint the glass in some manual way? I mean a post init or something? How you think?

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative, without having to set the width and height, you can always set the CSS property to fixed (using the !important directive)

```
.gwt-PopupPanelGlass {
    position:fixed!important;
}
```